# Uniform Convergence Complex Limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I want to confirm my understanding for this question.

''If $\sum M_n$ is a convergent series of constants, and the real valued function $u_n(z) < M_n$ for all n, does $\sum u_n(z)$ converge uniformly?''

If we let $M_n$ be a sequence of entirely constants, and pick something that's less than $M_n$ always, then it doesn't have to converge at all right?

Comment: What do you mean by "<" ? The lexicographic order on $\mathbf{C}$ ?

Comment: Remember the complex field has *no* linear order as the one in the real numbers field, so that Weierstrass M-test here requires $\;|u_n(z)|\le M_n\;\;\;\forall\,z\;$ and etc.

Comment: Sorry I editted the question, $M_n$ are not complex

Comment: @Joshua Then apply Weierstrass M-test directly.

Comment: Thank you. So $u_n$ converges uniformly if and only if $|u_n|<M_n$?